# java collection with multiple key and multiple row

Tags: java, collections

Please suggest an idea in collection to get array like this:

```
{ 
    {id=>1, name=>"aa"},
    {id=>2, name=>"bb"},
    {id=>3, name=>"cc"}
}
```

If I iterate through the array, the first time I give id means it should give 1 and the second time 2 should come.

Comment: are you aware of the name "classes". create a class and then use appropriate data structure.

Comment: now i try do like this only , but is there only way to achieve this functionality.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`public class obj{
String id;
String name;}`

and then have some thing like 
`List<obj>, or ArrayList<obj>`
`Map<obj,String> mp=new HashMap<obj, String>();`

Answer (score 3):

You can use an `ArrayList` to have a numerically indexed collection of Strings

```
ArrayList<String> list = new ArrayList<String>();
list.add("a");
list.add("b");
list.add("c");

for (int i = 0; i < list.length; i++) {
    // i = 0, 1, 2
    // string = a, b, c
    String string = list.get(index);
}

for (String string : list) {
    // string = a, b, c
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you want to use [Java's Map](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Map.html).  It's based on key/value pairs.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `LinkedHashMap` to get the result as you expected iff you inserted the data same way. Else follow the others suggestions if this is not the case you want.